# Creating an Image Comparison Slider doesnt hide but resizes/transforms the image like an accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

does anyone know whats wrong if the Image Comparison Slider that you can find on w3schools
doesnt hide but resizes/transforms the image like an accordion?

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp

any idea?

there is a slider but it does not cut of parts that should not be visible anymore after you move the slider. it resizes the image when you move the slider but you will see the transformed image that shows the entire image all the time until its completly gone..

Comment: Without a [reprex] there's little we can do. Don't make us guess...

Comment: well the entire code is provided on the webpage.. i just copied and pasted it but the problem, is that i use a framework that got its own css main file. i think the reason for transforming instead of just hiding content is that css file..